# VPN without port forwarding using raspberry pi and a VPS

Tags: vpn, openvpn, vps, tinc

I'm trying to setup a simple VPN without port forwarding.

I have:

- raspberry pi connected to a LAN (eth0 - 192.168.1.0/24)
- internet accessible vps server
- laptop & android device that needs access to the LAN using a VPN

I read that I can use tinc to establish a peer to peer connection between the raspberry pi and VPS server. This worked great so now I have created a network between vps and raspberry on 10.0.0.0/32 on dev tun0:

- VPS running tinc server 10.0.0.1
- Raspberry pi running tinc client 10.0.0.2 (subnet 10.0.0.0/32 & subnet 192.168.1.0/24)

From VPS I can access the LAN (e.g. 192.168.1.1) over ssh which is great. But the problem now is connecting to the VPS over a new VPN connectiong. For this I installed openvpn on the VPS.

This created a dev tun1 on the VPS, my VPS has 10.8.0.1. When I connect to the VPS over openVPN I get 10.8.0.2 on my client.

I issue is I cannot ping 192.168.1.1 or 10.0.0.2 from the client but I can ping 10.0.0.1.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I just need to add a postrouting and forward chain rule from tun1 to tun0.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: xepa, thanks for following up your own post with an answer! Is it possible to include a little more detail in the answer for folks in the future who may land here, even possibly including yourself :)

Comment: added some more details for future reference